# Testing WinForms user control - child control remains hidden

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, testing, user-controls

I am writing a WinForms user control in C# and want to test it (not TDD, I started by writing the component and making it work, but I kinda got tired of always finding bugs, so I want tests now). My problem is that I can't make a child control (a popup menu) become visible during testing. (I realize it won't show up - I don't *want* it to show up, but I still want to verify that it *would* show up when ran normally.)

Here's the relevant test code:

```
  updater.Raise(it => it.StateChanged += null, AutoUpdaterState.Ok);
```

[Note: the above is Moq code that will raise the event; it works, just ignore the details and think "event that will cause the menu to become visible is raised".]

```
  Assert.IsTrue(sut.checkToolStripMenuItem.Visible);
```

And here's the relevant code in the control:

```
      checkToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
```

The problem is... I put a breakpoint on this line, and Visible stays false after I run it. I understand it is probably because I'm testing it, and the menu doesn't actually become visible... which is ok, but how do I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing the UI code, it is often much simpler if it is properly structured using some sort of MVC pattern, MVP for example for WinForms (if you are not doing so yet).

When you write these tests, you shouldn't even have WinForms referenced in your test project. I usually have a method on the view, for your example it would be ShowPopupMenu(). What I test is that under certain circumstances the presenter will call this method. I don't test the particular method, because I leave these simple things to UI, 99% of logic is in presenter anyway; and to show the popupmenu it takes one line of code...

However, if you don't have MVP, there are some libraries that can help you test WinForms, like [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I like the MVP idea, but I don't understand how to actually test that "the presenter will call the [ShowPopupMenu()] method", since that method is also on the presenter, not on a collaborator (so I can't intercept the call). Do I add some flag or what?

Comment: Hmm I need to read more on MVP, I guess... I just realized presenter is not the same thing as view :P and that you said the presenter calls a method on the *view*. So, to restate for myself, you say I should have a non-UI pseudo-component (presenter) which will manage the actual UI controls (views), and only test this presenter - is that correct? I think I can work with that.

Comment: Yes, you separate everything from the view, so that view is so simple that it doesn't need tests. Check Passive View and Supervising Controller flavors of MVP.